# Difference between santhana gopalakrishna and navaneetha gopalakrishna

Tags: vishnu, idols

In case of murthi of santana gopalkrishna, he holds butter in one hand. In case of navaneetha gopalskrishna he holds butter in both hands. I am curious of this difference. I know the 24 roopas of vishnu with shanka,chakra,gada, padma in different combinations(4 factorial).
But there are more like the one above and like srikara with lakshmi sitting on the hand.
But I want to know the difference between santana gopalakrishna and navaneetha gopalakrishna